# Customize the Survey Questions Style in MS Team site

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-survey-list

I have this survey created on the MS Teams site. The survey question is so congested. I am trying to increase the width and add some padding but on the MS Teams site, you cannot add a script editor.

I am trying the column formatting to but no help.

I added HTML in the questions too but it prints the HTML instead.

```
{

 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",

 "elmType": "div",

 "txtContent": "@currentField",

 "style": {

  "padding-bottom":"30px''

 }
```

It did nothing, not sure it helps in SURVEY.
The below image is the survey questions. I am looking to increase the width and add some padding may be.
[image]

There is no scrip editor in MS TEAMS site. any other way we can make it work.

Comment: Please share your tab code so that we can repro at our end.

Comment: @user388969-  let us know if you still have issue on this

Comment: yes, the issue still exists @Sridevi-MSFT. not sure what is tab code. Create a survey on the TEAMS site and then try to add some look and feel customization, like change the color of survey questions or increase the size of the survey questions. I did not see any option of adding scripts and the column formatting i have above did not work.